# Store linq query as a variable without select statement

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to implement paging in LINQ based query. For this, I have to make two calls to the database, one is to get total records and others to fetch records.

```
var query = from dq in _context.QUEUEs
join rq in _context.REQUESTs on dq.REQID equals rq.ID
where dq.FLG == 0
select rq.ID;

int totalRecords = query.Count();

var result = from dq in _context.QUEUEs
join rq in _context.REQUESTs on dq.REQID equals rq.ID
where dq.FLG == 0
select new MyObject
{
    Request = rq,
    Queue = dq
}).Page(pageNumber, pageSize).ToList();
```

Is there any way I can combine my LINQ query and store it in some variable and then just execute `.Count()` to get count or `new MyObject{}`to get records?

Comment: ....you already store your query? in a variable called `query`?

Comment: Don't you already do it? You have `var query` which effectively stores your query in a variable. You can then just do `var count = query.Count()` and `var result = query.Skip(skip).Take(take).Select(x => new MyObject { Request = rq, Queue = dq});`

Comment: Maybe you should look at the PagedList library. Does it all for you. That said, @FranzGleichmann is right. You can use `query` again to get `result`: `query.Select(x => new { ... })`.

Comment: @DejanJanjušević: I guess you can not do `var result = query.Skip(skip).Take(take).Select(x => new MyObject { Request = rq, Queue = dq});` because `query` has `string` in its `select` statement

Comment: @Shaggy ah yes, missed that select, but you don't need it in the `query` variable so you can just omit it and select later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where your Page() method comes from but without that:

```
var query = from dq in _context.QUEUEs
  join rq in _context.REQUESTs on dq.REQID equals rq.ID
  where dq.FLG == 0
  select new MyObject
  {
      Request = rq,
      Queue = dq
  });

int count = query.Count();  // the Select() part should be ignored here
var results = query
      .Skip(pageNumber * pageSize, pageSize) // assuming pageNumer starts at 0
      .Take(pageSize)
      .ToList() ;
```

and of course async is preferable in a modern app. Same pattern.

Comment: Do you think, performing `.count()` on `select new MyObject  { Request = rq, Queue = dq  });` vs `rq.ID` will have some performance impact? There are about million records in that table.

Comment: I already put a comment in about ignoring the Select... but I'm never really sure. You have the code: measure.